# My program is crashing when flipping bits

Tags: c++, bit, bitmask

I have this function and apparently it causes my program to crash:

```
long long todos(long long x,long long i) {
  x ^= (1 << i);
  long long aux = i - 1;
  if(aux >= 0) x ^= (1 << aux);
  aux = i - 4;
  if(aux >= 0) x ^= (1 << aux);
  aux = i + 1;
  if(aux < 16) x ^= (1 << aux);
  aux = i + 4;
  if(aux < 16) x ^= (1 << aux);
  return x;
}
```

What I don't understand is why when I change all the `^= (` for `&= ~(` it runs perfectly fine (although the output I am getting is different). Is there any logical explanation for this behavior?

In case you need the entire code: http://ideone.com/Z7qoof

Comment: what do you mean by crash? can you post a report?

Comment: Does it crash within the function? Seems very unlikely?

Comment: The ideone link you provided runs fine. What kind of "crashing" are you observing?

Comment: The crash is a Stack Overflow

Comment: Here's a pic of what I get: http://pasteboard.co/18MaVY50.png And yes, like I said, if I change all the ``^=(`` for ``&=~(`` it doesn't crash.

Comment: May be you are just on the border of stack overflow and those bit operations alter the required stack size.

Comment: Does it really crash inside this function? Or is the crash caused somewhere else by the value returned by `todos()` (which of course changes when you change the operators).

Comment: btw "^= (" and "&= ~(" isn't the same thing.

Comment: @Angew I have tried doing this: ``if(n < 0 and (1 << 16) <= n) don't do anything`` but I'm getting the same thing and @auselen Yes, I know they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `dp()` function recurses very deeply.  Consider that a call to `dp(3)` can evaluate all 65536 possible bitboards in sequence with your `^`, while with your `&~` a call to `dp(k)` will only evaluate bitboards numerically before `k`.  Notice that you're filling in `mat` in order in `main()`; if you only depend on bitboards numerically before `k`, you won't recurse very deeply.

**EDIT**:  As for fixing this problem, you might think of dynamic programming as being of shortest paths in a directed acyclic graph.  The trouble is that you don't have an acyclic graph here.  You're doing depth-first search to find shortest paths here, which doesn't...work.  Try replacing it with something like breadth-first search or Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: But that's why I'm storing values, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your dp function recurses to a depth of 65252 when I run your code.  When I change xor to and-not in `todos()` and `soloUno()`, it recurses to a depth of 1.  This is because of the order in which you're filling in mat.  You're doing DP to reduce the total number of calls made, but it doesn't necessarily reduce the depth of the calls.

Comment: Now I'm doing this: ``cout << dp(bs.to_ulong()) << endl;`` instead of storing all the values and the program's still crashing.

Comment: Yes, that's because you changed something irrelevant without fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this line crashes:

cout << mat[bs.to_ulong()] << endl;

due to bs being bigger than the reserved space of 1<<16

p.s. why use the long long datatype for everything? long long is 64 bit. Most things you do could probably done with a short int

Comment: I changed all the ``int``s in the code for ``long long``s, just in case.